# Guide to migrate from react-redux v5 to v8

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux

i want to use new version of **react-redux** in my application. we use react-redux v5 and i want to migrate to v8.
But the gap between the two version look huge, i read the doc i think it's doable without too much risk.

But before starting the migration i would like to have your opinion on the possible breaking changes.

With the doc I see this for v6:

> The withRef option to connect has been replaced with forwardRef. If {forwardRef : true} has been passed to connect, adding a ref to the connected wrapper component will actually return the instance of the wrapped component.

> Passing store as a prop to a connected component is no longer supported. Instead, you may pass a custom context={MyContext} prop to both  and . You may also pass {context : MyContext} as an option to connect

[Doc v6](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/releases/tag/v6.0.0)
[Doc v7](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/releases/tag/v7.0.1)

Do you think of anything else and side effects ?
I accept all advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most users, the migration path is trivial:

`npm i react-redux@latest`

Done! :)

The public API has not meaningfully changed since v4.

The few small changes (such as the `withRef` option or custom contexts) are almost never used.

The *bigger* concern is if you're using other libraries that were reaching into React-Redux internals, such as accessing the legacy `this.context.store` value.  Examples of this were earlier versions of `redux-form` and `connected-react-router`.  In that case, upgrade those to the latest version.

Also: while it's not actually related to upgrading React-Redux, we also **strongly** recommend that you start updating your Redux logic to use our official Redux Toolkit package instead, which will make it much simpler and easier to work with:

- [Why Redux Toolkit is How To Use Redux Today](https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today)
- [Redux Fundamentals, Part 8: Modern Redux with Redux Toolkit](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux)
- [Redux Essentials, Part 2: Redux App Structure](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-2-app-structure)